# how to make a functional array?

Tags: java

```
String[] kelas = {" rizki" ," rifka"," putri"," sahal"};
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kelas));
    
    System.out.println( kelas[0]);
    for ( int i=0; 0 <= kelas.length; i++)
     {
        System.out.println("teman ke-"+1+ " adalah" + kelas[i]);
    }
```

hello i am try to make an array that will end like this :

```
[rizki,  rifka, putri, sahal]
rizki
teman ke-1 adalahrizki
teman ke-2 adalah rifka
teman ke-3 adalahputri
teman ke-4 adalahsahal
```

but in the end it said this

```
[rizki,  rifka, putri, sahal]
rizki
teman ke-1 adalahrizki
teman ke-1 adalah rifka
teman ke-1 adalahputri
teman ke-1 adalahsahal
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
   at javaapplication7.JavaApplication7.main(JavaApplication7.java:34)
C:\Users\Rizki Sultan Afian\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:Java  
returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

and this is the image:[the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkJTO.png)

i still dont understand java but i need to finish it for homework.

Comment: replace `<=` with `<`.

Comment: ...and `0` by `i`

Comment: In the end it should be like `for(int i=0; i < kelas.length; i++)`

Comment: thank you but the result is teman ke-1....,teman ke-1....,teman ke-1... how do i make it so it become teman ke-1...., teman ke-2..... , etc?

Comment: That's your homework. Why didn't you include the code as text in this question so that I could have looked at it? Links are not for code.

Comment: i may or may not pay enough attention at the class , but i am sure my teacher told me to make it from scratch. i already missed the original deadline and i didn't hear what should i do from the array. the teacher didn't attach the code to the assignment either.  i am really sorry

Comment: i already ask my classmate but she just send me the image of her work. that the only thing i know so far about the assignment.

Comment: it is okay, i found the answer. Thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong:

> ```
> for ( int i=0; 0 <= kelas.length; i++)
> ```

Should be:

```
for ( int i=0; i < kelas.length; i++)
```

Comment: but i didn't become teman ke-1... , teman ke-2.... , etc. instead it become teman ke-1.... , teman ke-1.... , etc. how do i fix this?

Comment: Isn't that your homework to do?

Comment: Well, `"teman ke-"+1+ " adalah"...` in the `System.out.printf` is why you get "...ke-1..." printed all the time.   Now, what do you suppose you should do about that?

Comment: change it into something else ? i didn't pay attention in the class.

Comment: @RizkiSultanAfian This is not difficult. Think about it. Hint: Replace the `+ 1 +` by something else.